# How to solve this forward class declaration problem?

Tags: c++, forward-declaration

I am having a following situation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Forward declarations
class Owner;
class Item;

class Owner {
public:
    string name;
    vector<Item> item;
    Owner(string _name, initializer_list<Item> _item) : name(_name), item(_item) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < item.size(); i++)
            item[i].owner = this;
    }
    // change the owner when copying...
    Owner(const Owner& o) {
        name = o.name;
        item = o.item;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < item.size(); i++)
            item[i].owner = this; // is this OK? 
    }
    Owner& operator = (const Owner& o) {
        name = o.name;
        item = o.item;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < item.size(); i++)
            item[i].owner = this; 
        return *this;
    }
};
class Item {
public:
    string name;
    Owner* owner;
    Item(string _name) : name(_name) {}
    string getInfo() {
        return name + " owned by " + owner->name;
    }
};
int main(){
    Item Cup("Cup"), Plate("Plate");
    Owner John("John", { Cup, Plate });
    cout << Cup.getInfo() << endl; // expecting "Cup owned by John"
    return 0;
}
```

One owner can have many items, but each item also must contain info about its owner. When I run this I get

> Error C2027 use of undefined type 'Item'

I thought this would be solved by using forward class declarations, but no such luck. Also, I'm guessing my copy constructor and assignment operators are OK?

Comment: I'd not make `Item` and `Owner` copyable (perhaps movable, but I'm not even sure).

Comment: you need to create these classes in different files with `.cpp` and `.h` extensions. In the header file of `Item`, you can use forward declaration and in `cpp` file include `Owner.h`. In the `Owner.h` you need to include `Item.h`

Comment: @Raffallo They don't need to be in different files. The definitions of the member functions need to follow the definitions of each class, but that can be done in one file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forward declaring the type is only part of the solution. You also need move defintions of functions of at least one of the types when dependencies are circular - usually put in .cpp file (but not neccesary as seen in example).

Working example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

// Forward declarations
class Owner;

class Item {
public:
    string name;
    Owner* owner;
    Item(string _name) : name(_name) {}
    string getInfo();//<-- only declaration now
};

class Owner {
public:
    string name;
    vector<Item> item;
    Owner(string _name, initializer_list<Item> _item) : name(_name), item(_item) {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < item.size(); i++)
            item[i].owner = this;
    }
    // change the owner when copying...
    Owner(const Owner& o) {
        name = o.name;
        item = o.item;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < item.size(); i++)
            item[i].owner = this; // is this OK? 
    }
    Owner& operator = (const Owner& o) {
        name = o.name;
        item = o.item;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < item.size(); i++)
            item[i].owner = this; 
        return *this;
    }
};

//or put in .cpp file
    string Item::getInfo() {
        return name + " owned by " + owner->name;
    }

int main(){
    Item Cup("Cup"), Plate("Plate");
    Owner John("John", { Cup, Plate });
    cout << Cup.getInfo() << endl; // expecting "Cup owned by John"
    return 0;
}
```

[Try it yourself](https://godbolt.org/z/EZA6Ww)

Furthermore, you **copy** the Items into the owner, so when you print the original, it only prints "Cup owned by " and "John", the owner, is missing. It's not clear which way this should be fixed - but could eg. be fixed by storing `std::shared_ptr` instead *if the items should be shared*.

Comment: But cout does not output anything in this case...?

Comment: @Tracer that maybe another mistake then. I got output "Cup owned by " - so missing John

Comment: @Tracer, I see now, you copy the object into owner - and the printing is of the original

Comment: I don't get any output. In fact, in debug I get the following exception "Exception thrown: read access violation. _Right was nullptr" on "basic_string& append(const basic_string& _Right)" in xstring header.

Comment: @Tracer that sounds unrelated - perhaps an error in your build, working example here https://godbolt.org/z/EZA6Ww

Answer (score 0):

When you use `std::vector<Item>`, `Item` must be a complete type.  In this case, you only use `Owner*` inside `Item`, so `Item` should come first.
Since you dereference the `Owner*` in `getInfo()`, its definition should come after the `Owner` class:

```
class Owner;

class Item {
    // ...
    std::string getInfo() const;
};

class Owner {
    // ...
};

std::string Item::getInfo() const
{
    // return ...
}
```

Comment: Then I get the message that Owner is not defined in function getInfo..

Comment: @Tracer `initializer_list` copies.  You are trying to associate the objects, not copy them.  And that's a new question ...